# How can I manage Languages?

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a problem configuring my own database and the relative codebehind making an application with Entity Frameworks that manage Languages.

Usually, in my old project I have a Table, let's say **Pages**, which contains unique row that identify a single page, with standard informations (that don't need translation at all):

```
ID
Author
Date
Location
```

Attached to this I have a support table **Pages_L** (1-N) that contains languages data, so specific informations translated for each page-row:

```
ID
ID_PAGE
LANGUAGE
Title
Description
Notes
```

Well, a standard configuration for a database! There is no redundancy of data.

The problem now become in Entity Frameworks, because for a specific page that I want to extract, I need every time to do a select:

```
1 - first the page (a `.Where`);
2 - than select the language (another `.Where`)
3 - finally, select the field I want (let say, `Title`)
```

I find this an annoying process, because when I do the query I need to extract the data only of a fixed Language. I mean: when my application is processing, language is ALWAYS one. I don't extract some in english, some in italian, some in francais, and so on.

So what I'd like to achieve it's a sort of "starting language point" for the whole context.
At later stage so, I just need to do:

```
Pages.Where(p=>p.ID==myID).FirstOrDefault().Title
```

without passing trought the **Pages_L** table every time.

The question is: can I do this in some way with Entity Framework? I can change everythings in my project, so every suggestions would be nice! (from DB, to entity framework, to others supply strategies).

Answer (score 0):

Hope I didn't misunderstand you.

Why don't you just write a method that returns the entire record you search for as an object and then from the returned object, reach the field you want? The method will return an object in type of Page but with the Include stuff, you can return a Page object with the Pages_L entity its related to, according to your limitations of course. Then you can reach any field of it in the part you want to. Like, let's call your method myQuery.

```
    Page page = myQuery(language, pageID);
    string ttl = page.Pages_L.Title;
```

This should work. If it does not, you can use a lambda expression to reach the Title or simply:

```
    Page page = myQuery(language, pageID);
    Pages_L pages_l = page.Pages_L;
    tring ttl = pages_L.Title;
```

should work.

Just write a method that returns Page and Pages_L together as a Page object, taking the proper LANGUAGE and ID arguments.

```
    public static Page (string lang, int pageID){
    YourDBName dbContext = new YourDBName;
    List<Page> pageList = ctx.Page.Include("Pages_L").Where(p=>p.ID == pageID);
    Pages_L pages_l = new Pages_L();
    foreach (Page page in pageList){
    pages_l = page.Pages_L;
    if(pages_l.Language == lang){
    return page;
    }}}
```

There should be a better way to make this query of course, that's a little lame to eliminate the records with foreach but I don't have a useful database to test such a query right now. Besides, you've got to call this function iff you'Re sure that there is at least one record. It is like "First" but not like "FirstOrDefault". However this should work if I didn't misunderstand your question. If this helps, you can improve the quality of the query with using multiple "Where"s and some lambda expressions; and without using List.

Answer (score -1):

For using different languages in your page you can use page resources,
It doesnt need to connect database for language values.
you can check ;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227427.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx

Comment: But the data I want to show is stored in the Database, so in some way I have to extract it...